# How to loop over a column and keep eliminating the last character of its string value as long as it doesn't create a duplicate in the column pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Here is what I'm trying to do.
I have a this pandas dataframe that consists of two column: Product ID and description.

Product ID is the identifier and it consists of characters that are specific to each product description.

What I am trying to do is to loop over each Product ID and eliminate the last characters of it until it only keeps the characters that distinguish the key from another

for example I have the below keys:

```
AA Product 1    AABBCC0050000
AA Product 1    AABBCC0100000
AA Product 1    AABBCC0250000
AA Product 1    AABBCC0500000
AA Product 1    AABBCC1000000
```

What I would like to have is the below:

```
AA Product 1    AABBCC00
AA Product 1    AABBCC01
AA Product 1    AABBCC02
AA Product 1    AABBCC05
AA Product 1    AABBCC10
```

Why I want to do that?

Because I want to match another dataframe with this dataframe on the substring that I would like to generate by this loop.

I would appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: If I follow your description, the first key would be "A"... or you supress only  numbers  it would be "AABBCC" ? Your description is not perfectly clear. Could you clarify when to stop/not supress? AABBCC00 woud be ok too.

Comment: Yes,  AABBCC00 would be ok too. I just edited that. If I only kept AABBCC that would mean having the same key for each row. I would like to distinguish the key as well as the product. I'm sorry if I'm unclear.

Comment: It could be slow and time consuming if you have many rows ... have you considered generating a unique int id / uid? it will be far more efficient. Strings/texts are slow to compute/work with.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because similarally formatted IDs exist in this other dataframe that I would like to match this one to and they both are more than 2000 rows. I would be happy if I discovered that there is no effecient way to get there. I just need to consume all my options before I give up :D

Answer (score 0):

```
characters_to_drop = 1

while len(df) == len(df["Product ID"].str[:-characters_to_drop].unique()):
    print(f"Product ID still uniquely identified after dropping {characters_to_drop}")
    characters_to_drop += 1

characters_to_drop -= 1  # Because the last iteration in the while loop augmented the character to count by one too much
```

Then `characters_to_drop` represents how many characters in the product ID can be dropped while preserving unique IDs and can be used to create a reduced Product ID column.

```
df["product_id_clipped"] = df["Product ID"].str[:-characters_to_drop]
```

All operations in this solution are vectorized and so will run very quickly/efficiently across a larger data set.